# Como definir os chutes iniciais para função nls para modelo de regressão potencial?

Tags: r

Gostaria de saber como definir os "chutes" iniciais para utilizar 
o modelo de regressão não linear de potencia. Estou trabalhando com estimação
de dados, testando vários modelos de regressão, mesmo não havendo ajuste,
gostaria de citar esse modelo, porém tenho dificuldades em definir os valores
iniciais, abaixo segue apenas um fragmento de dados para teste, gostaria de saber um método que me permitisse aplicar em qualquer conjunto de dados, para a obtenção dos valores inicias de A e B para a função `nls(y~B*x^A,start=list(A=1, B=1.7))`

```
dados<-structure(list(y = c(44.42, 77.9, 95.72, 40.24, 63.7, 46.62, 
84.6, 52.49, 88.53, 56.52, 71.21, 65.16, 72.24, 53.81, 67.02), 
    x = c(11.26, 14.78, 17.56, 10.37, 13.27, 10.3, 14.07, 12.26, 
    13.3, 12.84, 13.72, 12.8, 14.86, 11.47, 15.06)), .Names = c("y", 
"x"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

attach(dados)

nls(y~B*x^A,start=list(A=1, B=1.7))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Essa resposta](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/183776/44359) do Cross-Validated parece uma boa solução.

A sugestão aqui é tirar o log dos dois lados e ajustar um modelo linear. Que ficaria algo assim:

```
y = b*(x^a)
log(y) = log(b) + a*log(x)
```

Portanto, fazendo o modelo linear você terá uma estimativa inicial para `log(b)` e para `a`.

Ajuste o modelo linear:

```
linear <- lm(log(y) ~ log(x), data = dados)
linear
# Call:
#   lm(formula = log(y) ~ log(x), data = dados)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)       log(x)  
#        0.1371       1.5611
```

Assim você terá 0.1371 a estimativa de `log(b)` e `1.5611` estimativa de `a`.
Uma estimativa direta de `b` pode ser `exp(0.1371) = 1.146943`.
Esses valores podem ser utilizados como chutes iniciais.

```
modelo <- nls(y~B*x^A,start=list(A=coef(linear)[2], B = exp(coef(linear)[1])), data = dados)
modelo

# Nonlinear regression model
# model: y ~ B * x^A
# data: dados
# A     B 
# 1.436 1.598 
# residual sum-of-squares: 1040
# 
# Number of iterations to convergence: 5 
# Achieved convergence tolerance: 3.365e-07
```

---

No [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/183653/44359) tem outras várias respostas que podem ajudar!

Comment: Excelente resposta. Aplicar log em ambos os lados era a minha ideia para linearizar o problema e respondê-lo. Entretanto, esta pergunta não foge do escopo do site? Eu procurei perguntas sobre o assunto no [meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4266/como-lidar-com-uma-pergunta-que-depende-de-um-conhecimento-al%C3%A9m-da-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o/) e me parece que não há consenso entre os usuários a respeito do que fazer em casos assim. Particularmente, acho que tu agiu certo em responder, mas não existe o risco de vir alguém aqui e fechar a pergunta?

Comment: @MarcusNunes Obrigado! Para mim essa pergunta está na fronteira do "dentro" e "fora" do escopo... Existe o risco de alguém fechar, mas como está na fronteira, vais er difícil obter os 5 votos necessários. A resposta do [Carlos](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4355/6036) reflete bem a minha opinião. Ou seja, só não respondo se a pergunta não tiver nada a ver com programação. Aqui o problema do AP é mais: quero rodar o nls e não consigo pq da problema de convergência, como corrigir?. Ao meu ver, ele não veio pedir ajuda em estatística.

Comment: Levarei isto em conta nas minhas próximas respostas. Eu preciso aprender a responder o que é perguntado e não ir muito além na teoria estatística neste site.